# Printing 2 texts together in Python 3.7

Tags: python, text, printing

I'm testing the random module by creating a CCGen (not to use illegally, just cause it was the first idea I got). I don't know how I cant print 2 numbers attached (like printing 589903 and 3956371942 all together --> 5899033956371942).

This is the script:

```
import random

a = print ("")

x = random.randint (1000000000, 9999999999)

ccv = random.randint (100, 999)

month = random.randint (1, 12)

year = random.randint (2018, 2023)

print (a)

bin1 = input ("Please insert your BIN: ")
number = input ("Amount of CCs to generate: ")

for ccs in range(number):
    print bin1
```

My problem is in the end, thanks.

Comment: Your question is about python 3.7 (title) but you nevertheless have `print bin1` in your code like in python 2.X?

Comment: Sorry, just got on 3 from 2.7, yeah it's 3.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Side note, what are you trying to accomplish by binding the result of a call to print `print()` to a variable (`a`) and then `print`ing that value later (`print(a)`)?

Comment: I use it to leave spaces, so the script looks better when running